# How to avoid serving template files by Go

Tags: go

I'm writting small website on Go, and i found some problems, that i dont know how to solve. So...
The basic idea is to have one single folder for themes, called `/themes/` where we will put all our themes, f.e. `classic`, `modern`, etc.
The directory tree will looks like:

```
/themes/
    classic/
        index.html
        header.html
        footer.html
        css/
            style.css
        js/
            lib.js
    modern/
        index.html
        header.html
        footer.html
        css/
            style.css
        js/
            lib.js
```

So, my http handlers:

```
func main() {
    reloadConfig()

    http.HandleFunc("/", homeHandler)

    http.HandleFunc("/reloadConfigHandler/", reloadConfigHandler)

    // TODO: Theme loads html files also
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("themes/"+config.Theme+"/"))))
    http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
}
```

**The Problem**

The problem is that my templates files can be opened from the outside, if i open path `http://localhost/static/index.html`, so i need solution to:

1. Deny `/static/`, show 404.
2. Deny `/static/*.html`, show 404.
3. Allow `/static/{folder_name}/{file_name}`  so in future i can add `img` folder or `fonts` folder, and content inside of them will be served by server to client.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: How about adding `/static/css/` and `/static/js/` instead of `/static/`? The same way you’re doing it now, just twice and with different paths.

Comment: @ryan this is solution, but not flexible.. some day i will use `/css_minified/`, and also maybe add `/fonts/` and `/images/` or some other folders. This is solution, but not elegant way.

Comment: Mixing your templates and static files is the thing that’s considered inelegant in $current_year =) If you’re able to nest `css` and `js` in another `assets` directory and place your templates in `templates` (that part’s optional), that works too.

Comment: @Ryan this is also good idea to put `css` and `js` folders into `/assets/`. Maybe even better then write own handler for files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way is to implement your own `http.FileSystem`:

```
type fileSystem struct {
    http.FileSystem
}

func (fs fileSystem) Open(name string) (http.File, error) {
    f, err := fs.FileSystem.Open(name)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    stat, err := f.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // This denies access to the directory listing
    if stat.IsDir() {
        return nil, os.ErrNotExist
    }

    // This denies access to anything but <prefix>/css/...
    if !strings.HasPrefix(name, "/css/") {
        return nil, os.ErrNotExist
    }

    return f, nil
}
```

Now you can use it in your main like so:

```
fs := http.FileServer(fileSystem{http.Dir("themes/"+config.Theme+"/")})    
http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))
```

Comment: Yeah, thats what i need. Thanks. Can you please explain me, is there is possibility to turn off redirect from `/static/index.html` to `/static/`. I dont know why this happens, but it is, and only index.html, but footer.html is ok. Is there are any ways to solve this inside your func?

Comment: You would have to wrap the handler returned by `http.FileServer` and catch it there. This is not handled via `http.FileSystem` but `http.serveFile`. In any case, why would you care? The redirect leads to a 404 after following it.